# Multiply values in each row in 2d array then calculate grand total

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, multiplication

If I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
      (
            [Price] => 18.00
            [Quantity] => 2
      )
    [1] => Array
      (
            [Price] => 21.00
            [Quantity] => 1
      )
)
```

How can I sum and multiply the value to get `57.00` ?

I can sum but not multiply:

```
echo array_sum(array_column($datas, 'Price'));
```

Comment: You write a loop to process all the array items and maintain an accumulator to remember the total

Comment: Or `array_reduce`: `array_reduce($whatever, function ($a, $e) { return $a + $e['Price'] * $e['Quantity']; }, 0)`... Does this answer your question? [multidimensional array array\_sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838729/multidimensional-array-array-sum). Just add `* $e["Quantity"]` to just about any answer here; the `array_column`/`array_sum` combo doesn't work because it doesn't know how to apply multiplication, but anything that has a function body or loop body will give you a chance to apply the desired operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_map()` to multiply each price and quantity:

```
$total = array_sum(array_map(function($item) { 
    return $item['Price'] * $item['Quantity']; 
}, $datas));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It give me this error: `array_map() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`.

Comment: Pass your array as the second argument to `array_map`. I've updated the post since I'm sure that was Barmar's intent and it was just a typo.

Comment: So what is `$item` ?

Comment: That's each inner array of the outer array. You can `var_dump($item)` on each iteration of the callback to inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_product`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php) for the multiplication in this case.

```
$total = array_sum(array_map('array_product', $datas));
```

This will only work if those are the only columns in your data. If you have other columns that you aren't showing in the question, or if you add more columns to your data later, you'll have to specifically refer to the price and quantity columns like the other answers do.

For example: https://3v4l.org/qCHbZ

Comment: Yup, this is the most elegant solution for this task.

Comment: Also found identically [posted by you in 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50161013/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

You write a loop to process all the array items and maintain an accumulator to remember the total

```
$tot = 0;
foreach ( $array as $occ ) {
    $tot += $occ['Price'] * $occ['Quantity'];
}
echo $tot;
```